# Old props being used when rendering dynamically rendered list React/Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I am rendering content that I created by mapping over an array which returns an array that displays the items individually. I am using an index position from my store to determine what card is being shown. This works great but when I implement an onClick event, which takes the current index Im using from the store, then pushes content to an array using the index from the store things start to break down. It returns the initial index value instead of the current index value. This is simply isolated to the onClick event as I am using the index value in the actual render method and it is behaving as intended. I'm assuming this behavior is happening because when I am mapping over the list when the component mounts, it is binding the props of the initial value and not passing the updated value? Here is the code thats in question

// This is the hook that creates the list of cards

```
const [cardDeck, setCardDeck] = useState([])
    useEffect(()=>{
        renderCardArray();
    },[props.news])
```

// This is the function that calls the action creator

```
    const addToList = () =>{
        props.pushItemToReadingList(props.news[props.cardIndex]);
        props.increaseCardIndex();
}
```

// This is the map that gets set to a state value, that I can individually show

```
const renderCardArray = () =>{
    if(props.news.length > 1 && props.cardIndex < props.news.length){
        setCardDeck(props.news.map((item,iter)=>{
            return(
                <div className="card" ref={drag} key={iter}>
                    <h3>{item.title}</h3>
                    <img src={item.urlToImage} alt='News' style={{maxWidth: '200px'}} />
                    <button onClick={props.increaseCardIndex}>X</button>
                    <button onClick={addToList}>{'<3'}</button>
                </div>
            )
            }))`
```

// The 2ed button is returning an index of 0 every click, but the cards update with the proper index in the final return
// Here is the final return value of the component

```
return (
        <div>
            {cardDeck[props.cardIndex]}
        </div>
    )
}
```

// finally here is the connect and mapStateToProps

```
const mapStateToProps=(state)=>{
return {news: state.news, cardIndex: state.cardIndex}
```

}

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps,{
    pushItemToReadingList,
    increaseCardIndex
})(NewsCard);
```

If someone can help me understand why when I execute the addToList function it does not receive the updated index that the rest of the component is receiving? Also is there a better way to provide updated props to a mapped list?(I have temporarly solved this problem by switching around my action creator to not take an argument to push, it simply uses the store data internally but it doesn't help me understand why this behavior is happening) (also I am not planning on using local state and a redux store, I have split the two here simply to test this method of rendering and animating cards without having to write an additional action creator and reducer for my cardDeck)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a missing dependency `props.cardIndex` in your `useEffect` array, causing it to not update when `props.cardIndex` updates:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  if(props.news.length > 1 && props.cardIndex < props.news.length){
    renderCardArray();
  }
// renderCardArray depends on `props.cardIndex`, so
// make sure to add it here
},[props.news, props.cardIndex])
```

It would be clearer if the contents of `renderCardArray` were inline in `useEffect` (unless you need to call that function somewhere else). You could also pass `news` and `cardIndex` into `renderCardArray` to make it clearer what the dependencies are.

```
renderCardArray(props.news, props.cardIndex);
```

I'm not sure if that will solve your problem, but here are a few suggestions that might make the code easier to reason about/debug:

1. Use a value for `key` that's more stable than an index. Indices change if elements are added to/removed from the array, and it can cause bugs. If `item.title` is unique for each item, you can use that instead.
2. Set data in state, and limit JSX to what you return from your component. It looks like you only need to render one card at a time, and may not even need to store anything in local state:

```
const item = props.news[props.cardIndex];

return (
  <div className="card" ref={drag}>
    <h3>{item.title}</h3>
    <img src={item.urlToImage} alt='News' style={{maxWidth: '200px'}} />
    <button onClick={props.increaseCardIndex}>X</button>
    <button onClick={addToList}>{'<3'}</button>
  </div>
)
```

If you *do* need to keep an array of cards in state, keep the data instead of the JSX, and map over the `cardDeck` data when you return:

```
const [cardDeck, setCardDeck] = useState([])

useEffect(()=>{
  if(props.news.length > 1 && props.cardIndex < props.news.length){
    setCardDeck(props.news);
  }
},[props.news, props.cardIndex]);
...
return (
  cardDeck.map(card => (
    <div className="card" ref={drag} key={card.title}>
      <h3>{card.title}</h3>
      <img src={card.urlToImage} alt='News' style={{maxWidth: '200px'}} />
      <button onClick={props.increaseCardIndex}>X</button>
      <button onClick={addToList}>{'<3'}</button>
    </div>
  )
)
```

3. Actions should tell the reducer **what**, rather than **how**. They should describe what action happened, rather than how the reducer should update the state. This keeps all logic for the state in one place (the reducer), and makes a clean separation of concerns. Instead of `pushItemToReadingList` and `increaseCardIndex`, you could dispatch a single action `addItemToReadingList` and let the reducer be responsible for adding it to a stored list and increasing the index.